# Need to check if folder exists in workspace in groovy script for jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to check if a specific folder exists, I can not give the full path as some of the folder names will be different each time.

I used the below code -

```
echo "checking if folder exists"
def files = findFiles glob: '**/*example*'
echo """${files[0].name} ${files[0].path} ${files[0].directory} ${files[0].length} ${files[0].lastModified}"""
```

example is a folder which is inside -

java-maven-app/src/main/java/com/example

the error, I am getting in pipeline is -

[image: jenkins pipeline error]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your `files` list doesn't have any content. AFAIK `findFiles` is not capable of finding directories recursively. If you have any known files within the directory you are looking for you may be able to get the full path to that file using `findFiles` and determine whether your directory exists. But it will not work if the directory is empty. As a better solution, you can use the following script to get a list of all directories recursively.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
            def directories = getDirectories("$WORKSPACE")
            echo "$directories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@NonCPS
def getDirectories(path) {
    def dir = new File(path);
    def dirs = [];
    dir.traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES, maxDepth: -1) { d ->
        dirs.add(d) 
    };
    return dirs
}
```